# Use of Comma separator in Excel output file - C# webform

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I'm fairly new to C# so please bear with me. I'm attempting to write a data table to an Excel file - this works fine, however the number of columns in the data table have to be a variable number, dependent upon certain checkbox options added on the web form, which are checked by the user.

This is easy for the header columns, which are in-effect hard-coded, dependent upon the checkbox options selected.

The data for insertion into the data table is selected, and read using a while(sqldatareader.read) loop, and in that loop - again, dependent on the user options from the form, the elements of the table are added to a List of type string, which is declared outside of the loop.

A for loop, outside of this, then goes through the elements of the List and adds them to the data table (rows). All works well, and the number of records - and data - consistent with the data returned from the SQL database.

The issue: When writing to Excel, which in itself is working fine, I am trying to separate the values of the elements with a delimeter for writing to the Excel file - in this case a comma. However, appending a comma to each element in the list, outputs the comma as just another string, so the resulting elements are listed down the Excel file returned, as opposed to the comma behaving as a delimeter and duly moving to the next column in the data table.

Many thanks for any info in advance!

Code:

```
//initially declare list to hold elements of data table rows
List<string> elements = new List<string>();


    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
        //if option checked, add to List
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (ckVegName.Checked)
                    {
                        elements.Add(rdr["VegName"]);
                    }
                    if (ckFruitName.Checked)
                    {
                        elements.Add(rdr["FruitName"]);
                    }
                    if (ckJuice.Checked)
                    {
                        elements.Add(rdr["JuiceName"]);
                    }
                }
            }


//for loop to read elements
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
dt.Rows.Add(elements[i]);
}

//issue: if i add comma delimeter to this.. ie
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
dt.Rows.Add(elements[i] + ',');
}

/*
row value simply appends the comma as a character to
each returned value. I sort of expected this result, but wonder
if there is another way of forcing the code to accept a delimeter
and move to next row - instead of - as here, reading the comma
as just another char to append to each element?
*/
```

Comment: How are you writing the data out for Excel?

Comment: string attachment = "attachment;filename=data.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tb = "";

    /*then looping through (for loop) the columns and rows Thanks Chris

Comment: The end result is that the results are in a linear list down the entire file. If i hard code the dt.rows, ie.

dt.Rows.Add(rdr["VegName"], rdr["FruitName"]), rdr["JuiceName"]);

Then the columns are perfect. If the user options weren't variable, then this wouldn't be an issue. In the case above, the comma delimeter is not recognised as a string or char - but as a delimeter. The issue arises when i append (whether the example above or a StringBuilder) the comma to the loop - it just appends as a string character. Thanks.

Comment: consider `csv` instead of excel

Comment: Thanks abhitalks - i did, and the same result.

Comment: Right, just an update for anyone who is reading, problem is resolved. Instead of a data table, i have made use of a HTML table by simply adding "<td>" + rdr["VegName"] + "</td>", and appending to a string variable, insead of dt.Rows.Add(rdr["VegName"]. This works perfectly and is a lot less code. Just the out put needs to be done then, Response.Write(stringvar); to the Excel Response Type. Sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I think your issue is understanding the difference between a comma in a string and a comma used to separate arguments of a method.

Assuming that the working example in your comments *does work*:

```
dt.Rows.Add(rdr["VegName"], rdr["FruitName"], rdr["JuiceName"]);
```

Then maybe something like this is what you're after:

```
string vegName;
string fruitName;
string juiceName;

using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (ckVegName.Checked)
        {
            vegName = rdr["VegName"];
        }
        else
        {
            vegName = String.Empty;
        }

        if (ckFruitName.Checked)
        {
            fruitName = rdr["FruitName"];
        }
        else
        {
            fruitName = String.Empty;
        }

        if (ckJuice.Checked)
        {
            juiceName = rdr["JuiceName"];
        }
        else
        {
            juiceName = String.Empty;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(vegName, fruitName, juiceName);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks ForkandBeard, and that looks a pretty good solution for when using a datatable. I did find the resolution - ironically more simply - to make use of a HTML table, and build it that way (see my previous comment). This seemed to work best for my needs. Cheers and thanks again!